# Share y axes for subplots that are dynamically created

Tags: python, matplotlib

Working example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
names = ['one','two','three']
upper = [[79,85,88],[79,85,88],[79,85,88]]
lower = [[73,72,66],[73,72,66],[73,72,66]]
fig = plt.figure(1)
for idx,lane in enumerate(names):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,len(names)+1,idx+1)
    ax.plot(upper[idx], color='tab:blue', marker='x', linestyle="None")
    ax.plot(lower[idx], color='tab:blue', marker='x', linestyle="None")
    ax.set_title(lane)
plt.show()
```

This generates 3 plots dynamically. It works I could very well not be using the best practices for dynamically generating plots. The goal is to have all the plots generated share the Y-axis so that it will give it a cleaner look. All the examples I've looked up show that you can assign the shared axis to the previously used axis but in my case all the plots are created dynamically. Is there a way to just lump all the subplots in a figure into sharing the same y axis?

Comment: Did you try `fig = plt.figure(1,sharey=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach to creating a figure with multiple axes is [plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), which accepts a `sharey = True` argument.

---

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ydata_1 = np.sin(xdata)
ydata_2 = np.cos(xdata)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey = True, figsize = (8, 4))
ax1.plot(xdata, ydata_1)
ax2.plot(xdata, ydata_2)
```

This outputs:

[image: shared y axis plots]

For less space between the plots, you can also use a `tight_layout = True` argument.

---

Using your data, you could maybe rewrite it to something like

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(names), sharey = True, tight_layout = True)

for idx, (ax, name) in enumerate(zip(axes, names)):
    ax.plot(upper[idx], color='tab:blue', marker='x', linestyle="None")
    ax.plot(lower[idx], color='tab:blue', marker='x', linestyle="None")
    ax.set_title(name)

plt.show()
```

Comment: All the examples used the first example you shared. Works great knowing that it can return a list of axes. Slick solution.